# BLE - Decoding Advertisement with Python

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

Trying to get the advertisement from a Govee Hygrometer BLE device and decode the information to get Temperature and Humidity data. I've worked with both Bleak and Bleson to do this.

**I need help understanding the output and how to decode it to temperature and humidty.**

Here is my current script:

```
from bleson import get_provider, Observer
from time import sleep

def on_advertisement(advertisement):
    mfg_data = advertisement.mfg_data
    address = advertisement.address

    if mfg_data is not None:
        print("-" * 50, "Advert", "-"*50)
        print(f"""
          Device Name: {advertisement._name}
          Address: {advertisement.address_type}: {advertisement.address}
          Raw:{advertisement.raw_data} \t Raw Hex:{advertisement.raw_data.hex()}
          Mgf Date: {advertisement.mfg_data}        
        """)

adapter = get_provider().get_adapter()

observer = Observer(adapter)
observer.on_advertising_data = on_advertisement

observer.start()
while True:
    sleep(20)
observer.stop()
```

> Output#1:
> -------------------------------------------------- Advert --------------------------------------------------
> Device Name: None
> Address: PUBLIC: BDAddress('A4:C1:38:0E:E6:00')
> Raw:b'\x01\x04\x00\x00\xe6\x0e8\xc1\xa4\x0b\n\xff\x88\xec\x00\x11\t\x1a\x0fd\x02\xdb'
> Raw Hex:01040000e60e38c1a40b0aff88ec0011091a0f6402db
> Mgf Date: b'\x88\xec\x00\x11\t\x1a\x0fd\x02'

> Output#2:
> -------------------------------------------------- Advert -------------------------------------------------- \
> Device Name: None
> Address: PUBLIC: BDAddress('A4:C1:38:0E:E6:00')
> Raw:b'\x01\x04\x00\x00\xe6\x0e8\xc1\xa4\x0b\n\xff\x88\xec\x00\r\t\x17\x0fd\x02\xd4'      Raw Hex:01040000e60e38c1a40b0aff88ec000d09170f6402d4
> Mgf Date: b'\x88\xec\x00\r\t\x17\x0fd\x02'

**Looking to learn how to fish, not just be given a fish.**

- What is the difference between raw data and mfg data?
- How do I take the b'...' return and turn into actionable data?

Comment: Are you sure the advertisements contain the temperature and humidity values?

Comment: I've seen different resources doing the same with the Govee Hygrometers, so I know the BLE sends out the Temp/Humidity sensor, just trying to build a script to capture it

Comment: The manufacturing data is a sub-part of the full (raw) advertising data. This cheat sheet might be helpful to visualise the difference https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/blog/beacon-advertising-cheat-sheet/ . The iBeacon uses manufacturing data (type=0xff). Eddystone uses Service data (type=0x16). The full spec is at: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/